# Policies in using Youtube Iframe API in react native application

Tags: javascript, react-native, iframe, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

Is it legal to use YouTube videos as iframes in my React Native application?

I am developing a React Native application that has a large user base and generates revenue. I would like to use YouTube videos in my application, but I am not sure if it is legal to do so.

I know that YouTube allows developers to embed YouTube videos in their applications but does revenue factor affect that ?
I also know that YouTube has terms of service that developers must agree to before using YouTube's APIs.

My question is, is it legal for me to use YouTube videos as iframes in my React Native application? If not, is there another way that I can use YouTube videos in my application?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, it is legal** to use YouTube videos as iframes in your React Native application. However, there are a few things you need to keep in mind:

- You must comply with YouTube's terms of service. This includes things like not embedding videos that are age-restricted or that violate YouTube's community guidelines.
- You must include a link to the original YouTube video in your application. This can be done by adding a "watch on YouTube" button or by linking to the video's page on YouTube.
- You must not modify the YouTube video in any way. This includes things like changing the video's title, description, or thumbnail.
  If you follow these guidelines, then you are free to use YouTube videos in your React Native application.

I hope this information is helpful.